# MySQL: How to create new data record if unknown item and use new ID for insert into other table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables within MySQL 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-lo:

> - manufacturer

```
manufacturer_id
manufacturer_name
```

> - products

```
aticle_id
article_name
manufactuer_id
```

My goal is to insert a product if not already known and the same for the manufacturer. Therefore I created a unique index on the relevant column and do an INSERT IGNORE:

```
self.curr.execute(""" 
    INSERT IGNORE INTO products (
        `article_id`, 
        `article_name`,
        `manufacturer_id`, 
    ) 
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    """, (
        item['article_id'],         
        item['article_name'],
        1
    )

)
```

Now the problem is that first of all I need the manufacturer_id comming out of another table and if there is none, create a new manufacturer and use the newly created ID.

Something in the lines of

```
SELECT manufacturer_id
FROM tbl2
WHERE manufactuer_name = 'Coca Cola'

INSERT IGNORE
...
```

How can I create new products and manufacturers on the fly while inserting new products?

Comment: You want to create a manufacturer record when creating a product if the manufacturer doesn't exist? If so create a trigger on product and you would have to add manufacturer name later

Comment: That sounds like a plan. Would I be able to do that in one go before a commit?

Comment: mysql 8 can use functions as a generated column, but you still need a auto_increment ti get it unique

Comment: I am on  5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-lo. It would be not so important to add the product right away as during the next cycle it might get created. How would I use a trigger in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try adapting an insert select  ..

```
 INSERT  INTO products (
    `article_id`, 
    `article_name`,
    `manufacturer_id`
) 
select %s, %s,  manufacturer_id 
from manufacturer 
where manufactuer_name = 'Coca Cola'
```

Comment: The article_id is not an autoincrement value but an unique code_39 value I use.
Thank you for the example, what would happen if the manufacturer is unknown? The problem I am facing is, that in that case I would need to have a new manufacturer record created and the manufacturer_id used to also create a new article record.

Comment: answer updated ..  for article_id  .. if the manufacturer  is unknow  then you should leave the manufacturer_id  NULL  ..  and insert only the others values ..  or wai until you know the manufactuer

Comment: Thank you, it does not serve to 100% my case but I might be able to build on top of it.